# Plugin build failure with maven tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, tycho

I'm trying to build my Eclipse product with Tycho. I have all the pom structures created, with a parent pom in the root directory and child poms in product, plugin, and feature, but when I try to execute mvn clean veryfy or mvn install in a terminal in the root directory, the command fails.

This is the error that the console provides.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNEKE.png)

I tried to add repositories to the parent pom, trying to resolve the dependencies, but it didn't work.
I tried to add the repositories to Eclipse too, but it didn't work anyway.

Here is my parent `pom.xml`:

```
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sisnet.ide</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentSISnetRCP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho.version>2.7.5</tycho.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-15</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <eclipse-repo.url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest</eclipse-repo.url>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Enable the replacement of the SNAPSHOT version in the final product configuration-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>package-feature</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>
                                ${project.artifactId}_${unqualifiedVersion}.${buildQualifier}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Optional set the Java version you are using-->
                    <!--
                    <executionEnvironment>JavaSE-17</executionEnvironment>-->
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <!--TODO ADD YOUR MODULES HERE-->
        <module>com.sisnet.ide.target</module>
        <module>com.sisnet.ide.feature</module>
        <module>com.sisnet.ide.plugin</module>
        <module>com.sisnet.ide.product</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: Missing requirement: `com.sisnet.ide.plugin` (which I guess is your plugin) requires `org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui` 7.10.0 or higher.

Comment: I already have or.sonarlint.eclipse.ui in the dependencies of my plugin but the error remains.

Comment: By that you declared that it is required, but it's missing in your target platform.

Comment: but how can i add to the target platform if i dont have the repository to add it to the location window of the target platform?

Comment: By the way, Tycho with [`.mvn/extensions.xml`](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/.mvn/extensions.xml) requires only a parent `pom.xml` (so-called POM-less). See also [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) and [this example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Please show your target definition file.

Comment: The update site of SonarLint is [`https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org`](https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org). See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint

Comment: If i delete the pom archives from the plugin, product and feature the build fails, the console says that i have no pom for this modules. And i already followed this tutorial you send me and doesnt work for me, maybe im not understanding the process, but i followed the steps one by one.

Comment: In my target definition i added this site: Eclipse Repository - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-06/, but i dont know how to add the sonarlint site to have the dependencies.

Comment: In fact, when i add the site i posted on last comment, eclipse gives me this error:  Problems ocurred while resolving the target contents

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to help. Anyway, see my answer below. Consider to start with a [working Tycho example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) and then adapt it to your needs which is IMHO easier than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that your plugin `com.sisnet.ide.plugin` requires `org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui` 7.10.0 or higher, but which is missing.

In your target definition file (`*.target`) add the following location:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <unit id="org.sonarlint.eclipse.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
    <repository location="https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org"/>
</location>
```

Comment: The console still with the same error, i think the problem is not in the target platform

Comment: You might have more errors (e.g. not correctly included the target definition), but if SonarLint is required as in your case, the target definition must contain a location containing SonarLint. There might other p2 repositories than `https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org` containing SonarLint. SonarLint cannot be found in a release p2 repository at download.eclipse.org. Sorry, but I can only answer the question you ask. I asked you to show what you have, but you didn't.

Comment: I already solved the problem, the mvn clean verify and install works, but now i need a executable with my custom eclipse, did you know how to do it?

Comment: See my customized Eclipse built with Tycho here: https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized

Comment: what should i search for in you github? i didnt see nothing that explains how to obtain an executable, maybe its my fault.

Comment: You mean a product that can be installed, right? After you have built the plugins and features, you have to build the [product](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/pom.xml#L35).

Comment: I dont understand concretly what are you saying. This is my folder structure https://i.postimg.cc/cHSGgtB3/image.png  and this is my parent pom. https://i.postimg.cc/9Q86pNtc/image.png https://i.postimg.cc/YqyRycVD/image.png https://i.postimg.cc/mrqh0jRs/image.png I execute mvn clean verify, and then mvn install and that generates me the 3 target folders, in product, plugin and feature folders. https://i.postimg.cc/x8Qm45yd/image.png https://i.postimg.cc/MGDJBKPr/image.png https://i.postimg.cc/dQRNtSf4/image.png I dont know what i should do now because i want a exe with my eclipse product.

Comment: In you parent POM you specified p2 repositories (not recommended) instead of using a target platform (recommended). What is used must be built before it is used. Your target platform `<module>com.sisnet.ide.target</module>` is the last instead of first Maven module in your parent POM, so it is not used. You have to switch the order of `<module>com.sisnet.ide.feature</module>` and `<module>com.sisnet.ide.plugin</module>` if the feature contains the plugin. You will find the output in `com.sisnet.ide.product/target/products/`. Generally, please add your parent `pom.xml` as text to your question.

Comment: https://secure-text-sharing.sisnet360.com/?201455d6c4c94f9e#HyRErE9ycKxurGBG7ZfgHfdDL9YiBUfJf7UkukLLCSCH Here it is my parent pom.

Comment: Hello again, I managed to make it works thanks to your project structure, but my custom personalization like icons and splash doesnt appear in the ide when i execute the mvn install.  Any advice about that?

Comment: What do you mean with _"doesnt appear"_? If files or folders are missing in the output `com.sisnet.ide.product/target/products/`, you probably forgot to add them in [`build.properties`](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/org.idealized.customization/build.properties).

Comment: I created this product using Java 11, but i have a problem upgrading to Java 17, the icons, menu toolbar and perspective that i created doesn't appear in the exported product but the splash remains. I installed jdk 17 in my machine but i dont know why this personalization doesn't show except for the splash. I have all of them added in the build.properties like you said.

Comment: Better upgrade to latest Tycho (which is currently 3.0.4) first.

Comment: Are there any problems by upgrading to java 17 or...

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/QtPYZ3sh/image.png This is what happens when i add the last version of tycho

Comment: You need to run Maven with Java 17 or higher when using Tycho 3.x. Java 17 is more restrictive than Java 11. So some adaptions or upgrading of dependencies might be needed, especially when reflection is used.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to work nicely. We are going to try it now.

Comment: Hello again, im triying to upgrade this proyect by adding more features that allows me to do more things and i have problems with the target platform dependencies. I dont find the p2 repositories links to add to the target. Is there any solid way to search the sites that you need to add to the target platform? I've read about a project made by igor fedorenko to seach for p2 repositories but i didnt manage to make it work.

Comment: Plugins/features to install can be found on the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) with their update site URLs (which are mostly p2 repositories, otherwise can be converted). Needed dependencies of bundles/plugins that are not contained in `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest` can be often found in [Orbit](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/). Orbit will be more and more replaced by the possibility to download JARs from Maven Central and convert them on the fly into OSGi bundles (if they are not already).

Comment: I managed to search the repos with oomph tool but when I add required plugins to my main plugin, the mvn install goes succesful but when i start the generated product it doesnt have any customization, my custom perspective, menu item and icons doesnt appear, and the product doesnt even have the plugin i added. Im triying to add m2e.wtp to my product to have maven. I already added the required repo to my target platform. Do u have any idea of what is that behaviour?

Comment: Adding a feature to the target platform is not enough (the target platform tells only where something can be found), you have it also added to the product. See e.g. m2e.pde [in the target platform](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/target-platform/idealized-target.target#L30) and [here added to the product](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/product/idealized.product#L87) (the ID of the install unit differs from the feature ID by the `.feature.group` suffix).

Comment: If this does not answer your question, you might ask it as a separate question with more information.

Comment: With your configutation, I doesnt lose my configuration, but i want maven in my product and i dont have it. These links are my target platform https://ibb.co/VqSPTR2
https://ibb.co/FnTt0G0
https://ibb.co/Xb4wQBg
https://ibb.co/6Fxh7gg, i know i have duplicated repos, its because i used part of yours. And this is my product https://ibb.co/80Nr3M5
https://ibb.co/W3Q37St

Comment: Which files are exactly missing in your product that has been built? Your target with `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group` and your product with ``org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature` looks fine to me. By the way, `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group` is also contained in `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`. Better use `version="0.0.0"` and specify a version only if you don't want the highest version (only in rare cases a repository contains more than one version of the same thing).

Comment: The build product doesnt contain maven, and dont alow me to create maven projects. I dont know why.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ngX0xmt These are my build product preferences, Maven should be there.

Comment: Please show what is in the `features` folder of your installed product? It's the same as generated with Maven/Tycho in `com.sisnet.ide.product/target/products/.../features`, right?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZmM9KqJ
https://ibb.co/3Sxj4LR This is the content of my features folder

Comment: Your product contains `<feature id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature" installMode="root"/>`, so Maven/Tycho should fail or create a product with a `features/org.eclipse.m2e.feature_<version>/` folder. Maybe you are building a different product or looking at the wrong directory. Delete your output directory `com.sisnet.ide.product/target/`, run your build and see whether it will be recreated. Make also sure to increase the version number when you add something (or use the suffix `.qualifier"` in the version to get timestamp).

Comment: I tried few things but maven still doesnt appear in my product. This is my features folder. https://ibb.co/BNf1xZv  Is org.eclipse.m2e.feature the one that makes maven appear in the product?

Comment: Yes, `org.eclipse.m2e.feature` contains the `org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui` plugin with the Maven preference pages. When you start your product, will there anything in the error log, telling why `org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui` cannot be started?

Comment: nothing visible, is this error log hidden in some folder?

Comment: In your product, go to the _Error Log_ view or look directly into the `<workspace>/.metadata/.log` file.

Comment: Yeah, there are few errors, https://ibb.co/1Kyt5VX.

Comment: You need to run your product with Java 17 or higher. Consider to include the Java 17 VM as a feature ([`<feature id="org.eclipse.justj.epp" installMode="root"/>`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product#n235)).

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer, i had to add two more features and one more repository but for now is working. Thank you.